# Reading .h5ad file in R using Convert

Tags: r, seurat

I'm trying to read a .h5ad file in my RStudio.

I first converted the .h5ad file to .h5Seurat file using the `Convert()` function in `library(SeuratDisk)`.

The code for my attempt can be found here:

```
> library(Seurat)
> library(SeuratDisk)

> Convert("train.h5ad", "train.h5Seurat")
Warning: Unknown file type: h5ad
Warning: 'assay' not set, setting to 'RNA'
Creating h5Seurat file for version 3.1.5.9900
Adding X as data
Adding X as counts
Adding meta.features from var
Adding X_Compartment_tSNE as cell embeddings for Compartment_tSNE
Adding X_tSNE as cell embeddings for tSNE
Adding layer counts as data in assay counts
Adding layer counts as counts in assay counts
> train_seurat <- LoadH5Seurat("train.h5Seurat")
Validating h5Seurat file
Error: Ambiguous assays
```

The data which I'm trying to read can be found here: `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1cXYoKNU9qY0f1bbYNh2uykWG6juVJln7`

To add, I tried:

```
> train_seurat <- LoadH5Seurat("train.h5Seurat", assays = "RNA")
```

But I faced the same issue. Trying to find something quick.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly try the `anndata` library but note that the data type won’t be `seurat` as you would want. It’ll be an `anndata` class object.

Comment: this creates `anndata` data class object and the functions for `seurat` class objects won't be available for `anndata`, can you suggest some other alternatives.